# 613 threads limit on debian

Tags: linux, debian, threads, multi-threaded

When running this program [thread-limit.c](http://people.redhat.com/alikins/tuning_utils/thread-limit.c) on my dedicated debian server, the output says that my system can't create more than around 600 threads. I need to create more threads, and fix my system misconfiguration.

Here are a few informations about my dedicated server:

```
de801:/# uname -a
Linux de801.ispfr.net 2.6.18-028stab085.5 #1 SMP Thu Apr 14 15:06:33 MSD 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
de801:/# java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
de801:/# ldd $(which java)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbc3fd000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002af013225000)
        libjli.so => /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so (0x00002af013441000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00002af01354b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00002af013750000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002af013008000)
de801:/# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
1589248
de801:/# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 794624
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 128
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Here is the output of the C program

```
de801:/test# ./thread-limit
Creating threads ...
Address of c = 1061520 KB
Address of c = 1081300 KB
Address of c = 1080904 KB
Address of c = 1081168 KB
Address of c = 1080508 KB
Address of c = 1080640 KB
Address of c = 1081432 KB
Address of c = 1081036 KB
Address of c = 1080772 KB
100 threads so far ...
200 threads so far ...
300 threads so far ...
400 threads so far ...
500 threads so far ...
600 threads so far ...
Failed with return code 12 creating thread 637.
```

**Any ideas how to fix this please ?**

Comment: Did you try /etc/security/limits.conf?

Comment: yes i did. it doesn't change anything, nor ulimit settings.

Comment: This programming question relating to `ENOMEM` returns from `pthread_create()` was asked and answered on StackOverflow in August 2010.

Comment: That is an out of memory error, so the issue isn't a thread count cap, but some other limit.  Your stack size is small.  You might want to think about migrating this to stackoverflow.

Comment: @JdeBP Could you please provide a link to this answer ?

Comment: @Paul: They told me to migrate from stack oververflow to here :) And it's not memory related, i have tried other values for stack size. It's a CAP limitation in the OS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419283/pthread-create-enomem-around-32000-threads

Comment: @DragonLord: This question answers how to go over a 30K threads limits and i'm stuck at 600 threads.

Comment: It's been asked at least 7 times on StackOverflow, _twice_ in August 2010 alone.  You want the _other_ time, for starters.  Put the keywords into StackOverflow's search box, and read all of the questions and answers that come up.  You're just as capable of doing a search on StackOverflow as I am, now that you know the names of the function and the error.

Comment: @JdeBP You don't understand what this question is about. Please refrain from giving answers to things that are too complicated for you. It pollutes the available space for legitimate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the following information: This is a limitation imposed by my host provider. This has nothing to do with programming, or linux.

Comment: That's drivel on its face.  _Of course_ it has something to do with programming and Linux.

Comment: You are wrong. No it doesn't. It's a limitation artificially imposed by my server's host, who has customized debian's kernel.

Comment: … which makes it to do with the _Linux_ kernel and pthreads _programming_, kiddo.  Please put the old brainbox in forward gear.  This should be blatantly obvious, even to those who haven't twigged that this is one of a series of _programming questions_ asked by you about a program that you are writing.

Comment: Yes I am asking questions about a program that I am writing. That's what those exchange sites are for. And you could never write such a program with your slow brain, sorry for you.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try changing the thread stack size, from the o/p of ulimit -a it shows it's "128".

try changing to 1024; **ulimit -s 1024**

Let me know the results.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried every possible value for ulimit -s, going from 64K to 1024, 2048, more, and even unlimited. In any case, 600 threads is the limit on my system.

Comment: what's the system memory n is this 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bits with 2GB physical memory.

Comment: RLIMIT_STACK does not bound the space consumed by thread stacks, though it does influence the default stack size of new threads.  As such increasing it is not likely to help in this case.  In some cases it could even make things worse.